# How to see which option in Pull-Down Menu is selected in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I've been stuck on an assignment. In the assignment I have to use a Pull-Down Menu to change what is displayed from the database. So, for example if option A is selected then courses and grades will be shown.If on the other hand option B is selected then everything on the database will be shown. I though that if I name the options like `<option value = "1" name = "Reg" >Student Registration</option>` then use `if (isset($_POST['Reg']))` it would work , but now I'm thinking maybe this is not the correct way to solve this issue. I'll include a snippet of the HTML code that has the menu and the full PHP code.

```js
<?php
include("account.php");
//connect to MySQL database
session_start();
$dbc = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL database");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
$user = $_POST['name'];
$num = $_POST['number'];
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    if (empty ($user)) 
    {
        echo "you must enter your unique username <br />";
    }
    if (empty ($num)) 
    {
        echo "you must enter your ID <br />";
    }
   
 $query = "SELECT * FROM StudentDB WHERE StudentName = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$user) ."' AND StudentID = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$num) ."'" ;
 $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) 
 {
       if (isset($_POST['Reg']))
    {
     echo 'Student Name: ' . $row['Student Name'] . '| Student E-Mail: ' . $row['E-Mail'] .';'. '| Student ID: ' . $row['Student ID'] . '| Student Courses: ' . $row['Student Courses'] .'| Student Transcript: ' . $row['Student Transcript'] .'<br />';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['Tran']))
    {
     echo 'Student Name: ' . $row['Student Name'] . '| Student E-Mail: ' . $row['E-Mail'] .';'. '| Student ID: ' . $row['Student ID'] . '| Student Courses: ' . $row['Student Courses'] .'| Student Transcript: ' . $row['Student Transcript'] .'<br />';
    }
 }
 else
 {
  echo"unsuccessful login";
 }
session_destroy();
}
else
{
  echo "Empty";
}
?>
```

```html
<TD>
 <select id = "myList">
    <option value = "1" name = "Reg" >Student Registration</option>
   <option value = "2" name = "Tran" >Student Transcript</option>
  </select>
</TD>
```

If the full HTML code is need , just ask and I'll add it. So, to summarize the question I asked : **Is there a way to use `if (isset($_POST[]))`to check which option on the Pull-Down Menu is selected , if not then what other method can I use to do that?**

Thank You

EDIT:

I changed my HTML and PHP code to :

```js
<?php
include("account.php");
//connect to MySQL database
session_start();
$dbc = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL database");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
$user = $_POST['name'];
$num = $_POST['number'];
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    if (empty ($user)) 
    {
        echo "you must enter your unique username <br />";
    }
    if (empty ($num)) 
    {
        echo "you must enter your ID <br />";
    }
   
 $query = "SELECT * FROM StudentDB WHERE StudentName = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$user) ."' AND StudentID = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$num) ."'" ;
 $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) 
 {
       if (isset($_POST['list'] == '1'))
    {
    }
    if (isset($_POST['list'] == '2'))
    {
    } 
 }
 else
 {
  echo"unsuccessful login";
 }
session_destroy();
}
else
{
  echo "Empty";
}
?>
```

```html
 <TD>
 <select id = "myList" name = "list" >
   <option value = "1" >Student Registration</option>
  <option value = "2" >Student Transcript</option>
 </select>
</TD>
```

This causes it to crash when I click submit. When I change the PHP code to this:

```js
<?php
include("account.php");
//connect to MySQL database
session_start();
$dbc = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL database");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
$user = $_POST['name'];
$num = $_POST['number'];
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    if (empty ($user)) 
    {
        echo "you must enter your unique username <br />";
    }
    if (empty ($num)) 
    {
        echo "you must enter your ID <br />";
    }
   
 $query = "SELECT * FROM StudentDB WHERE StudentName = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$user) ."' AND StudentID = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$num) ."'" ;
 $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) 
 {
       /* if (isset($_POST['list'] == '1'))
    {
    }
    if (isset($_POST['list'] == '2'))
    {
    } */
 }
 else
 {
  echo"unsuccessful login";
 }
session_destroy();
}
else
{
  echo "Empty";
}
?>
```

it works. The change I made is just commenting out the section in-between `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){}`

Comment: easy, if isset($POST['selectName'] == '2'){ }.. 2 being the value of the option. But options shouldn't be named. You want the SELECT to be named, and options to only have value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way: Select should be named and options only have value

```
<TD>
    <select id = "myList" name='listItems'>
    <option value = "1">Student Registration</option>
      <option value = "2">Student Transcript</option>
  </select>
</TD>

if(isset($_POST['listItems'] == '1')){

}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it just crashes. I changed the html to have the name in the selected and just the values in option. I changed the php line to : `if (isset($_POST['list'] == '1'))` with list being the select name, but after doing this the site just crashes. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Something else is off because syntax is right and it wouldn't crash

Comment: When I comment the section out, the code works ( does not crash) , but when I add it in it crashes. I don't really know what else could be wrong, since I already test the rest of it ( it was used in another part of the assignment). Maybe this is affecting something its not suppose to .

Comment: Show me what you did exactly

Comment: I edited my original post to show what I did and what I removed to test  to make it work. I removed the echo because they did not do anything at the moment.

Comment: Try assigning the variable above with the rest of your post as $choice = $_POST['list'];.    Then below doing a test like if($choice == '1'){ } etc

Comment: Yep That stopped the program from crashing and is catching the choices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an option pre-selected based on the data fetched from your database, right?

If so, your code can't work but this should do it (not tested though):

```
<select id = "myList" name="type">
    <option <?php if ($_POST['type'] == "1") { echo "selected"; } ?> value = "1" >Student Registration</option>
    <option <?php if ($_POST['type'] == "2") { echo "selected"; } ?> value = "2" >Student Transcript</option>
</select>
```

Comment: For what I need the program to do is to have the user select the option ( i.e Registration or Transcript) and click submit. The PHP code will then check to see if Registration was selected or if Transcript was selected, then based on the selection to do stuff. I want to keep the php and HTML code separate. So, I don't think I need it pre-selected because it will only be check after the submit is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Change the HTML so name is part of select instead of the options:

```
<td>
    <select id="myList" name="opt_selected">
        <option value="Reg">Student Registration</option>
        <option value="Tran">Student Transcript</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Then check the value of `$_POST['opt_selected']` to see if it equals Reg or Tran.

Answer (score 0):

'Reg' and 'Tran' are just two possible values of the select list, which is what you're actually posting.

Instead of `(isset($_POST['Reg']))`, use `($_POST['myList'] === 'Reg')`.